# mysql `order by` result incorrect

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql query that looks like:

```
(SELECT datum AS dt, dat1, dat2, num FROM maanden WHERE DATE_FORMAT(datum, '%Y') >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 YEAR, '%Y') AND DATE_FORMAT(datum, '%Y') < DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR, '%Y') ORDER BY datum ASC)
UNION
(SELECT datum AS dt, dat1, dat2, num FROM maanden WHERE DATE_FORMAT(datum, '%Y') >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR, '%Y') AND DATE_FORMAT(datum, '%Y') < DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') ORDER BY datum ASC);
```

Result:

```
+---------------------+------+------+-----+
| dt                  | dat1 | dat2 | num |
+---------------------+------+------+-----+
| 2015-01-01 00:00:00 |  165 |    0 | 127 |
| 2015-02-01 00:00:00 |  101 |    0 |  81 |
| 2015-03-01 00:00:00 |  120 |    0 | 124 |
| 2015-04-01 00:00:00 |  106 |    0 |  49 |
| 2015-05-01 00:00:00 |  101 |    0 |  20 |
| 2015-06-01 00:00:00 |  117 |    0 |  19 |
| 2015-07-01 00:00:00 |  136 |    0 |  17 |
| 2015-08-01 00:00:00 |  184 |    0 |   8 |
| 2015-09-01 00:00:00 |  117 |    0 |  20 |
| 2015-10-01 00:00:00 |  173 |    0 |  59 |
| 2015-11-01 00:00:00 |  169 |    0 |  74 |
| 2015-12-01 00:00:00 |  257 |    0 | 108 |
| 2016-02-01 00:00:00 |  217 |    0 | 151 |
| 2016-03-01 00:00:00 |  123 |    0 |  72 |
| 2016-04-01 00:00:00 |  145 |    0 |  44 |
| 2016-05-01 00:00:00 |  169 |    0 |  30 |
| 2016-06-01 00:00:00 |   92 |    0 |   7 |
| 2016-07-01 00:00:00 |  143 |    0 |   9 |
| 2016-08-01 00:00:00 |  155 |    0 |   9 |
| 2016-09-01 00:00:00 |  150 |    0 |  11 |
| 2016-10-01 00:00:00 |  162 |    0 |  64 |
| 2016-11-01 00:00:00 |  170 |    0 | 113 |
| 2016-12-01 00:00:00 |  243 |    0 | 124 |
| 2016-01-01 00:00:00 |  190 |    0 | 123 |
+---------------------+------+------+-----+
24 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

Why is `2016-01-01 00:00:00` the last row? If I do last years only (no `UNION`):

```
(SELECT datum AS dt, dat1, dat2, num FROM maanden WHERE DATE_FORMAT(datum, '%Y') >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR, '%Y') AND DATE_FORMAT(datum, '%Y') < DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') ORDER BY datum ASC);
```

I get the proper result, being:

```
+---------------------+------+------+-----+
| dt                  | dat1 | dat2 | num |
+---------------------+------+------+-----+
| 2016-01-01 00:00:00 |  190 |    0 | 123 |
| 2016-02-01 00:00:00 |  217 |    0 | 151 |
| 2016-03-01 00:00:00 |  123 |    0 |  72 |
| 2016-04-01 00:00:00 |  145 |    0 |  44 |
| 2016-05-01 00:00:00 |  169 |    0 |  30 |
| 2016-06-01 00:00:00 |   92 |    0 |   7 |
| 2016-07-01 00:00:00 |  143 |    0 |   9 |
| 2016-08-01 00:00:00 |  155 |    0 |   9 |
| 2016-09-01 00:00:00 |  150 |    0 |  11 |
| 2016-10-01 00:00:00 |  162 |    0 |  64 |
| 2016-11-01 00:00:00 |  170 |    0 | 113 |
| 2016-12-01 00:00:00 |  243 |    0 | 124 |
+---------------------+------+------+-----+
12 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Tried the last query with `()` and without `()` but no difference. Any help appreciated!

Comment: My guess would be a difference in timezone configuration for mysql and whatever created the dates which you have stored. Could that be the case?

Comment: I could make the query easier by doing `SELECT datum AS dt, dat1, dat2, num FROM maanden WHERE DATE_FORMAT(datum, '%Y') >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 YEAR, '%Y') AND DATE_FORMAT(datum, '%Y') < DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') ORDER BY datum ASC;`. This does produces the correct result and therefore solves the question. What is doesn't do is solving the _reason_ behind the question...
@Rogier Could be. Do you know how I can find out?

Comment: Yes that would solve it as well as the order by is applied to the entire set. not individual queries prior to the union.  If you think about it you told the engine to order set 1 which it does 1,2,3  and set 2) 3,4,5,6.  Then you told it to UNION (which does a distinct and likely changes the ordered results) so it then the engine combines the two sets, but no order by has been defined for the combined set; thus the engine combines it in a way which it believes is most optimal since no order by has been defined.  your comment query then works since the engine is able to apply the order by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order by on each query is overhead.  You need to Order by the entire union set.  Otherwise each order by is only applied to the individual query.

Since no order by is indicated for the entire union, the engine could return the results in any defined order, it just happens to be with 2016-12-01 being last.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT datum AS dt, dat1, dat2, num 
      FROM maanden 
      WHERE DATE_FORMAT(datum, '%Y') >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 YEAR, '%Y')   
        AND DATE_FORMAT(datum, '%Y') < DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR, '%Y') 
      UNION 
      SELECT datum AS dt, dat1, dat2, num 
      FROM maanden 
      WHERE DATE_FORMAT(datum, '%Y') >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR, '%Y') 
        AND DATE_FORMAT(datum, '%Y') < DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y')
     ) 
ORDER BY datum ASC;
```

Comment: I see. I guess I use my own comment answer for this individual case but I now know at least what happens with `ORDER BY` in any subsequent queries that I apply. I'll accept the answer, Thanks xQbert!

Answer (score 1):

Your query works as designed. The behaviour is specified in the [documentation of the `UNION` SQL statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html):

> Use of `ORDER BY` for individual `SELECT` statements implies nothing about the order in which the rows appear in the final result because `UNION` by default produces an unordered set of rows. Therefore, the use of `ORDER BY` in this context is typically in conjunction with `LIMIT`, so that it is used to determine the subset of the selected rows to retrieve for the `SELECT`, even though it does not necessarily affect the order of those rows in the final `UNION` result. If `ORDER BY` appears without `LIMIT` in a `SELECT`, it is optimized away because it will have no effect anyway.
>
> To use an `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT` clause to sort or limit the entire `UNION` result, parenthesize the individual `SELECT` statements and place the `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT` after the last one.

Consequently, the query that does what you intended is:

```
(
    SELECT datum AS dt, dat1, dat2, num 
    FROM maanden
    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(datum, '%Y') >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 YEAR, '%Y')
      AND DATE_FORMAT(datum, '%Y') < DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR, '%Y')
)
UNION
(
    SELECT datum AS dt, dat1, dat2, num
    FROM maanden
    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(datum, '%Y') >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR, '%Y')
      AND DATE_FORMAT(datum, '%Y') < DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y')
)
ORDER BY datum ASC
```

---

As a side note, your query can be simplified (and its speed increased) by using the [`YEAR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) function instead of `DATE_FORMAT()`. Its speed can be improved even more by pre-computing the first and the last day (or datetime) of the years you want to compare and then comparing `datum` against them.